# Trigger event of kendo scheduler control dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

How can I trigger or fire or invoke save method of kendo scheduler control from moveEnd. once I preventDefault moveEnd event?

```
function scheduler_moveStart(e) {
    log("moveStart", e);
}
function scheduler_move(e) {
    log("move", e);
}
function scheduler_moveEnd(e) {
    log("moveEnd", e);
    e.preventDefault();
    // my logic goes here
    //
    // line of code
    //  
    // fire save event from here.
}    
function scheduler_save(e) {
    log("save", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about saving the scheduler's event, so you can use [`saveEvent()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#methods-saveEvent) method. But, there is another option which you can save dataSource's data, in case you have added the event in your dataSource prior to save in database, by using [`sync()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-sync):

```
function scheduler_moveEnd(e) {
    log("moveEnd", e);
    e.preventDefault();

    var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");

    // Saving by scheduler's saveEvent()
    scheduler.saveEvent();

    // Saving by dataSource's sync()
    scheduler.dataSource.sync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay; this both scenarios not working for me.
Do you have any other solution?

Comment: If I do not prevent the event, all scenario working fine.  but when once event is prevented from moveEnd, its not saving the moved event or not working as expected.

Comment: @HardikSavani so it works if you take away `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Yes. I want to check for existing event on moveEnd slot. so I'm preventing the event.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this using below code:
use editEvent and pass current event as argument.

```
e.sender.editEvent(e.event);
e.sender.saveEvent();
```